# Custom posts and custom taxonomies for many products and categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm a little confused about custom posts and custom taxonomies...
I've read it everywhere but I didn't understand very well..

I would build a wordpress site, with many products, categories, feature and options...
They will just order the products, without paying, so I don't need an e-commerce plugin..

Now the really question is: how can I organize the products in categories? I have to customize wordpress posts, to assign various feature and options, like the article code, or the color?

I have to use custom taxonomies? (I have a vague idea of what it is...)

Thanks in advance for who will help me.. I'm a little confused about this type of wordpress customization...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like making a custom post type called "Products" would be the best way for you to manage the products.

Unless you want a special name for the taxonomy, you could just make your custom post type use the default "Category" taxonomy for organizing your products.

The simplest way to add data like article code, color, etc to your products is to just use "custom fields". This is something else you have to tell your custom post type to support, like the category taxonomy.

It didn't sound like you were asking for it, but if you want a more technical "How to" answer, let me know in a comment below.